How can you run lldb in macOS without root permissions?
Running LLDB in macOS requires root permissions to 'take control over another app'.
This is pissing off IT support in my company who don't want anyone to have root access on their machines.  Is there a way to build and debug processes without sudo?

Allowing your app to be debugged is opt-in on Darwin, signaled by adding the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement to your application.  If you are building your App in Xcode, by default Xcode will add this entitlement to your Debug configuration products (but not to the Release configuration).  If you are using another build system you'll have to add that entitlement by hand.
You can override an opt-out choice and debug some apps that didn't opt in to being debugged - though not ones that request sensitive entitlements - if you debug as root.  But if you are just debugging apps you built locally, you should use the entitlement instead.
This was discussed some more here:
What does get-task-allow do in Xcode?
Though at that point the entitlement was just get-task-allow.
